# Drop down menu over d3 SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm stuck. I want to add an html drop down menu over an SVG chart that I've created using d3. Currently the drop-down menu appears below the chart, but I want the drop-down menu to appear over a specific location on the chart.

I'm unclear if my problem is with the order in which browser renders all of the elements or if it's simply an CSS issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="chartArea">
  <select class = "demoSelection"></select></div>
```

Here's my css:

```
  .chartArea{
      position: relative;}

    .demoSelection {
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      top:400px;
      left:250px;}
```

Here's where I create the SVG element in d3:

```
  var svg = d3.select("body").select(".chartArea")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("id","svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("class","chart");
```

I later populate the selection box with options in d3

```
  d3.select(".demoSelection")
       .append("option")
       .attr("value",demoCounter)
       .text(json.demos[demoCounter].title);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any mistake in the scripts you have provided.

I tried to recreate the scenario with the inputs you have provided but not able to recreate however I am putting my working code.

This might help you.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").select(".chartArea")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .append("g").attr("class", "chart");

var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, width]);



var bar = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

d3.select(".demoSelection")
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", 1)
    .text("Hello");
d3.select(".demoSelection")
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", 2)
    .text("Another Hello");
```

```css
.chartArea {
    position: relative;
}
.demoSelection {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    top:40px;
    left:25px;
}
.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="chartArea">
    <select class="demoSelection"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code!  It proved it was possible, and something was off with my code.  After comparing your css element styles with my own in chrome I saw that my .css class were not being picked up correctly.  Turns out it I had a nesting issue in SASS.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `z-index: 10;` in the CSS for your demoSelection class.

Comment: No change.  The main issue is that the drop-down is appearing below the chart and not on-top of it.  If it were appearing on-top of the chart, but was not visible z-index would probably work.